# Использует ли кэш запросов встроенный профайлер в MySQL?

Tags: mysql

Мне интересно, используется ли кэш при работе встроенного профайлера MySQL. Например, если я выполняю запрос

```
mysql> select count(*) from comment;
```

а после выполняю этот же запрос с профилированием:

```
mysql> set profiling=1;
mysql> select count(*) from comment;
mysql> show profiles;
```

Чисто эмпирически похоже, что кэш не используется. Но хотелось бы знать это точно. В документации на этот счёт я ничего не смогла найти. Надеюсь на помощь.